# Mechanical design for base of robotic arm

Tags: robotic-arm, design

I am using DC motors to build a robotic arm.  I want to make the base shoulder (which rotates and lifts) more stable and stronger.  How should I design this using DC motors?

Also I would like to put the motor for the elbow in the base for efficiency.  Which design best suits this?

**UPDATE**
I am building a robotic arm for a payload of approx. 1-2 kg and using DC high torque motors. In this model, I am using only a shoulder with a gripper. The gripper is self made by me weighing approximately 400 grams. I want to have a proper design and material choice so that the shoulder part remains less heavy and more stable.

In addition to this I want to operate the movement of the gripper, i.e. the up and down motion, by using the motor in the base part. What should be my design and better alternative?

Comment: Could you give some more explanation of your current design concept, so that more effective answers can show up?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my question with some more details.

Comment: how many total degrees of freedom will it have?  2 in the base and 1 in the elbow + 1 in the gripper?  what is the length of the arm?  what is the intended use?  what kind of sensing will it have / need?  how fast / accurate does it have to be?  you need to provide much more information if you want informed answers.

Comment: it will have a degree of freedom of 2 in base, 1 in elbow and 1 in gripper, The length of arm includes 30-35 cm from shoulder to elbow end, 10 cm from there to gripper or less. The use of this arm is for lifting or simply can say pick and drop like function. I am using ATmega32 right now for programming and speed is not an issue right now.

Answer (score 2):

We built a robot arm similar to the model in the following link.

http://www.3ders.org/articles/20131113-make-your-own-3d-printed-trainable-robotic-arm.html

We used 3D-printer to print all the links so the link mass is small but strong enough. BTW we only used cheap servos but the arm moved not bad so I think the high torque motors are okay. I suggest you start with a 3 DOF arm and if you want any design reference you can search on grabcad.com. There are plenty of great design models. Have fun!